# OneSignal not working after update React Native Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, onesignal

I have followed the guidelines of version 3.2.12,

and followed the instruction in the official document, but player id is not getting generated please help.

Initialization stopped after upgradation to 3.2.12, now they are not supporting initialization on componentWillMount()

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  I18nManager,
  AsyncStorage,
  Platform
} from "react-native";
import {
  Container,
  Right,
  Item,
  Input,
  Header,
  Left,
  Body,
  Title,
  Form
} from "native-base";
import FontAwesome from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
// Screen Styles
import styles from "../Theme/Styles/Signin";
import Logo from "../image/qualpros.png";
import axios from 'axios';
import AwesomeAlert from 'react-native-awesome-alerts';
import OneSignal from 'react-native-onesignal';

class TutorSignInScreen extends Component {
  
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
    showAlert: false,
    message: '',
    
  }

  state = {
    data: [],
    email: null,
    password: null,
    device_id: null,
    showAlert : false   
  }

  constructor(properties) {
    super(properties);
    OneSignal.init("my-onesignal-id");

    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
  }


  componentWillUnmount() {
    OneSignal.removeEventListener("received", this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener("opened", this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener("ids", this.onIds);
  }

  onReceived(notification) {
    console.log("Notification received: ", notification);
  }

  onOpened(openResult) {
    console.log("Message: ", openResult.notification.payload.body);
    console.log("Data: ", openResult.notification.payload.additionalData);
    console.log("isActive: ", openResult.notification.isAppInFocus);
    console.log("openResult: ", openResult);
  }

  onIds(device) {
    let playerid = device.userId;
    //console.log("Device info: ", playerid);
    AsyncStorage.setItem('playerid', playerid);
    this.setState ({
      device_id: playerid
    })
  }

  

  showAlert = () => {
    this.setState({
      showAlert: true
    });
  };

  hideAlert = () => {
    this.setState({
      showAlert: false
    });
  };

  signIn = async () => {
    let device_type = (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 'ios' : 'android' 
    try {
      let { data } = await axios.post('url', {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password,
        //device_id: this.state.device_id,
        device_id: '123test',
        device_type: device_type
      })
        .then((response) => {
          
          
          if (response.data.data.status === 'success') {
            this.setState({ data: response.data.data })
            console.log(response.data.data)
            AsyncStorage.setItem('username', response.data.data.user_info.username);
            AsyncStorage.setItem('userType', response.data.data.user_info.user_role_name);
            AsyncStorage.setItem('latitude', response.data.data.user_info.latitude);
            AsyncStorage.setItem('longitude', response.data.data.user_info.longitude);

            
            AsyncStorage.setItem('user_id', response.data.data.user_info.user_id.toString());
            AsyncStorage.setItem('user_role_id', response.data.data.user_info.user_role_id.toString());
            this.props.navigation.navigate(response.data.data.user_info.user_role_name === 'Student' ? 'App' : 'Tutor')
          } else {

           
            this.setState({
              message: response.data.data.message,
              showAlert: true,
          })


          }
        })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  showAlert = () => {
    this.setState({
      showAlert: true
    });
  };

  hideAlert = () => {
    this.setState({
      showAlert: false
    });
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header style={styles.header}>
          <Left style={styles.left}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.backArrow}
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Welcome")}
            >
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <FontAwesome name="angle-left" size={30} color="black" />
                <Text style={{ margin: 5, marginTop: 6, color: "black", fontSize: 12}}>Back</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </Left>
          <Body style={styles.body} />
          <Right style={styles.right} />
        </Header>
        <View style={styles.logosec}>
          <Image source={Logo} style={styles.logostyle} />
        </View>
        <Form style={styles.form}>
        
          <Item rounded style={styles.inputStyle}>
            <Input
             
              textAlign={I18nManager.isRTL ? "right" : "left"}
              placeholder="Email"
              style={styles.inputmain}
              onChangeText={(email) => { this.setState({ email }) }}
              autoCapitalize='none'
            />
          </Item>
          <Item rounded style={[styles.inputStyle, { marginTop: 10 }]}>
            <Input
              
              placeholder="Password"
              secureTextEntry={true}
              textAlign={I18nManager.isRTL ? "right" : "left"}
              style={styles.inputmain}
              onChangeText={(password) => { this.setState({ password }) }}
              autoCapitalize='none'
            />
          </Item>
          <TouchableOpacity
            info
            style={styles.signInbtn}
            onPress={this.signIn}
          >
            <Text autoCapitalize="words" style={styles.buttongetstarted}>
              Sign In
              </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ForgetPassword')}>
            <Text autoCapitalize="words" style={styles.buttongettext}>
              Forgot your password?
              </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Form>
        <View style={styles.bottomView}>
        


          {/* <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.fbButton}
            onPress={() => alert("Facebook button Clicked")}
          >
            <View iconRight style={styles.fbview}>
              <Ionicons name="logo-linkedin" size={30} color="white" />
              <Text autoCapitalize="words" style={styles.fbButtonText}>
                Sign in with LinkedIn
                </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity> */}
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.bottomText}
            onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('TutorSignUpScreen') }}>
            <Text style={styles.bottomText01}>
              Don&apos;t have an account?{" "}
              <Text style={styles.bottomText02}>Sign up</Text>
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        
        <AwesomeAlert
                    show={this.state.showAlert}
                    showProgress={false}
                    //title="QualPros!"
                    message={this.state.message}
                    closeOnTouchOutside={true}
                    closeOnHardwareBackPress={false}
                    showConfirmButton={true}
                    confirmText="Ok"
                    confirmButtonColor="#d91009"
                    onConfirmPressed={() => {
                        this.hideAlert();
                    }}
                    />   
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
export default TutorSignInScreen;
```

environment:
"react-native-onesignal": "^3.2.12",
"react": "16.6.1",
"react-native": "0.57.7"

Comment: Have you tried using componentDidMount instead?

Comment: I did but it is still not working

Comment: for the time-being, I have downgraded to 3.2.4 and it is working. Will see if we can upgrade to 3.2.12 if I get a proper answer